# Amazon IAP not launching purchase dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm migrating an app from the play store to the Amazon App store, considering that in this way it will be avilable for Windows 11 too.

For this to make something very fast and easy i made an activity called PurchaseActivity which contains the codes brought by the amazon IAP guide PDF.

The activity is called from a "buy now" button of a dialog window with the following code:

```
public class PurchaseActivity extends Activity {
String parentSKU = "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine";
//Define UserId and MarketPlace
private String currentUserId;
private String currentMarketplace;
private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Purchasing");
    progress.setMessage("Wait while making the purchase...");
    progress.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            progress.dismiss();//dismiss dialog
            finish();
        }
    });
    progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
    progress.show();

    PurchasingService.registerListener(this, purchasingListener);

    PurchasingService.purchase(parentSKU);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //getUserData() will query the Appstore for the Users information
    PurchasingService.getUserData();
    //getPurchaseUpdates() will query the Appstore for any previous purchase
    PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(true);
    //getProductData will validate the SKUs with Amazon Appstore
    final Set<String> productSkus = new HashSet<String>();
    productSkus.add(parentSKU);
    PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus);
    Log.v("Validating SKUs", "Validating SKUs with Amazon");
}


PurchasingListener purchasingListener = new PurchasingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUserDataResponse(UserDataResponse response) {
        final UserDataResponse.RequestStatus status = response.getRequestStatus();
        switch (status) {
            case SUCCESSFUL:
                currentUserId = response.getUserData().getUserId();
                currentMarketplace = response.getUserData().getMarketplace();
                Log.v("IAP SDK", "loaded userdataResponse");
                break;
            case FAILED:
            case NOT_SUPPORTED:
                // Fail gracefully.
                Log.v("IAP SDK", "loading failed");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductDataResponse(ProductDataResponse productDataResponse) {
        switch (productDataResponse.getRequestStatus()) {
            case SUCCESSFUL:

                //get informations for all IAP Items (parent SKUs)
                final Map<String, Product> products = productDataResponse.getProductData();
                for (String key : products.keySet()) {
                    Product product = products.get(key);
                    Log.v("Product:", String.format("Product: %s\n Type: %s\n SKU: %s\n Price: %s\n Description: %s\n", product.getTitle(), product.getProductType(),
                            product.getSku(), product.getPrice(), product.getDescription()));
                }
                //get all unavailable SKUs
                for (String s : productDataResponse.getUnavailableSkus()) {
                    Log.v("Unavailable SKU:" + s, "Unavailable SKU:" + s);
                }
                break;
            case FAILED:
                Log.v("FAILED", "FAILED");
                progress.dismiss();
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse) {
        switch (purchaseResponse.getRequestStatus()) {
            case SUCCESSFUL:
                PurchasingService.notifyFulfillment(purchaseResponse.getReceipt().getReceiptId(),
                        FulfillmentResult.FULFILLED);
                break;
            case FAILED:
                progress.dismiss();
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse response) {

        // Process receipts
        switch (response.getRequestStatus()) {
            case SUCCESSFUL:
                for (final Receipt receipt : response.getReceipts()) {
                    // Process receipts
                    if (!receipt.isCanceled()) {
                        // sharedprefs
                         SharedPreferences sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor = sharedPreference.edit();
                        sharedPrefEditor.putBoolean("isPro",true);
                        sharedPrefEditor.apply();
                        progress.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                if (response.hasMore()) {
                    PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(true);
                }
                break;
            case FAILED:
                Log.d("FAILED", "FAILED");
                progress.dismiss();
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Yeah i know i should not call all that stuff in the onStart() method but i'll make an onCreate() with a UI later.

As you can see from this code, i'm testing in sandbox mode.

THE PROBLEM: Actually when the activity starts, i see progressDialog, and i read in the debug logs that "V/Validating SKUs: Validating SKUs with Amazon" but i don't see then the amazon buy window. It also seems like the listener code is never called, even if i put some breakpoints in there, they're never reached which is very weird considering that apprently it gets initialized and called successfully by the method "PurchasingService.registerListener(this, purchasingListener)"

Any help would be very apreciated!

Thanks and have a good evening

Comment: You are calling purchase too early, your IAP isnt yet ready I think..

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `registerListener` in your Application's `onCreate`, otherwise Amazon fails to detect there's an Activity being displayed and it will not show the purchase dialog.